# Creating seed file combining two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, seed

How to set up my seed file to create my data with associated records?

So far I have:

```
# Arrays
strand = ['Oracy across the curriculum', 'Reading across the curriculum', 'Writing across the curriculum', 'Developing numerical reasoning', 'Using number skills', 'using measuring skills', 'Using data skills']
component_array = Component.all.map(&:id)

# Add each item in array
strand.each { |sample| Strand.create(name: sample) }
```

The relationship being:

```
component has_many :strands
strand belongs_to :component
```

Within this I want to assign `component_array[0]` to the first 3 elements in my array and `component_array[1]` to the remaining 4 elements.

What syntax should I use, would I be looking at a hash here?

Comment: what is the relationship between `Component` and `Strand`? Is it `Strand belongs_to :component` & `Component has_many :strands`?

Comment: apologies, forgot to add the relationship, just added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather easy to assign models to their relationships.

In your case, the `Strand` **belongs_to** `Component`

```
name_arr = ['Oracy across the curriculum', 'Reading across the curriculum', 'Writing across the curriculum', 'Developing numerical reasoning', 'Using number skills', 'using measuring skills', 'Using data skills']
components = Component.all

name_arr.each_with_index do |name, index|
  strand = Strand.new(:name => name)

  # associate a component to your strand
  # this will add the component_id of your strand
  strand.component = components.first if index < 3
  strand.component = components[1] if index >= 3

  strand.save
end
```

Likewise, to assign a **has_many** relationship

```
component = Component.new(:foo => :bar)
strand = Strand.new(:name => 'Oracy across the curriculum')

# assign it to the strand, automatically adds fitting id
component.strands << strand
component.save
```

Comment: thanks for your help but this doesn't create and index value for some reason

Comment: index is returning nil values